# Regular Expression - date format

Tags: regex

I have the text:

```
*Name:    Danny   Birthday: 23/05/71
*Person:  Natan   Birthday: Jan. 27 1964
*Name:    Emily   Birthday: 11/09/77
*Person:  Alex    Birthday: Feb. 27 1964
*Person:  Mark    Birthday: Mar. 27 1964
```

I have tried regular expression like this: (Jan.|Feb.|Mar.|Apr.|May.) but Person Mark also marked. What should be expression that only Month. is marked?

Comment: `.` is a special character in regex and it matches any character (except newline) which explains why `Mark` was matched... So, to match a literal dot, you must escape it `\.`... [`DEMO`](https://regex101.com/r/dX5xY5/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape '.'
It is being matched with any character.

Try this

```
(Jan\.|Feb\.|Mar\.|Apr\.|May\.)
```

---

Instead of this better use single dot in the end

```
((Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May)\.)
```

Comment: Isn't it same as OP is using?

Comment: Yes, the backslash got escaped.
Corrected.

Comment: Thanks.I also defined expression that work:(\S*Mar.\s\b)|(\S*Jan.\s\b)|(\S*Feb.\s\b)

Comment: Please escape _all_ the dots... this regex is painful to look at.